# GeoPandas intersetion dataframe exclude border

Tags: geopandas, intersection

I have GeoDataFrame of zones with poligons. I have to find which of them are intersected. But zones have common border. How could i exclude common border from intersercion?

```py
admzones = admzones[['zid', 'geometry']]
together = geopandas.sjoin(admzones, admzones.set_index('zid'))
together.loc[together.zid != together.index_right]

# zid|geometry|index_right
# 519|POLIGON()|514
#...

...

geo1 = admzones[admzones['zid']==519]
geo2 = admzones[admzones['zid']==514]

geo1['intersection'] = geo1.intersection(geo2, align = False)
geo1['intersection'].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you mock up this example & expected output with simple polygons (like triangles) hard-coded into a GeoDataFrames?